# SQL query to update the column values while using Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using Sql Server management studio. I have a temporary table with two fields in it,  1. RowNumber and 2. Percentage

Now, I want to group by similar Rownumbers and find the average of Percentages values of those corresponding to same Rownumbers. How do I write a query to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe include a diagram of the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
SELECT RowNumber, AVG(Percentage) as ave_percent
FROM t_your_table
GROUP BY RowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
UPDATE yt
SET RNo = ytg.ap
FROM YourTable yt
JOIN    (   SELECT RNo, AVG(Percentage) ap
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY RNo
        ) ytg ON ytg.RNo = yt.RNo
```